Do hypervalent compounds exhibit delocalized pi bonding
The NBOs of ozone or benzene (2e - 3c pi bonds) employs delocalized pi systems while it retains a localized sigma framework. This can be used for example to account for double bonds or lone pairs that move around in resonance structures. This can also be used to draw resonance hybrid which accurately reflect the true nature of molecules in a simple intuitive VBT style making them useful.
If we take a hyper coordinated compound like sulfur hexafluoride, how would we draw the NBOs or IBOs so that it accurately yet intuitively accounts for the shifting ionic bond in the SF6 resonance structures like in ozone. Would we employ similar techniques to ozone where we keep localized framework but have delocalized pi system across the molecule?
we can employ resonance structures with shifting ionic bonds (e.g sulfur hexafluoride has a shifting ionic bond and 4 real covalent bonds). If we try to calculate NBOs of SF6 from localizing the MOs, how would we rationalize shifting ionic bond and the 8 electron - 6 center system or the 4/5 bond 1/5 ionic bond resonance hybrid.
Edit: After doing some further research, I realized chemical like ozone, sulfur trioxide have NBO description of 4 electron 3 center bonds. In some compounds like Krypton difluoride or triiodide ion - this can be applied for VBT or NBO description to sigma bonds though unlike pi bonds, I haven't had confirmed validity on this. Is there anything similar to this but for hexacoordinated hyper valency and greater like Xenon hexafluoride, iodine heptafluoride

For y aromaticity you need ay shaped molecule. Neither ozone nor benzene are that. In MO theory all bonds are delocalised, so that is a perfectly reasonable assumption of a binding picture. Iirc NBO has an option to try to recognise such systems. Anyway, hypervalent is a quite old term and can't properly encompass that. Use hypercoordinate instead. In resonance structures electron pairs don't move around, only the mathematical description changes. So this is all just something trying to rationalize another thing...

Most hypervalent/hypercoordinate molecules are nonplanar, so there is no real diatinctiin between pi and sigma bonding. You often get occupied MOs that are pi bonding between one pair of atoms and sigma bobding (or even sigma antibonding) between a different pair.
